# How do I host a Django project's admin static files?

Tags: django, apache, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I've heard I should use Apache for serving static files in a production environment. I'm having some problems understanding how I'm supposed to do that though. My project's static URL is `/static/`, and `django.contrib.admin`'s static path is `/static/admin/`. Those are two completely separate directories on my server, and I can hardly do this:

```
Alias /static /path/to/site.com/static
Alias /static/admin /usr/local/.../django/contrib/admin/media
```

Since they overlap.

How am I supposed to do this? Do I really have to copy the contrib admin static folder into my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, no-one says you have to serve your admin static files from the same base path as the others. You can set `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` to whatever you like.

However, surely the easiest thing is just to add a symlink from your static folder to django/contrib/admin/media.

Comment: For people stumbling on this answer — `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` has been deprecated in 1.4. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9960831/1226722) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Common solution is using /media/ for admin media static files, so it could be in settings.py

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
```

and in virtual host config:

```
Alias /media /path/to/django/contrib/admin/media/
<Location /media>
    SetHandler None
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the order of the `Alias` entries and Apache will parse it as intended:

```
Alias /static/admin /usr/local/.../django/contrib/admin/media
Alias /static /path/to/site.com/static
```

This is because when Apache loads its configuration, it stores entries from a top down perspective. So it first tries to match `/static/admin`, then if the URI doesn't match, it then tries to match `/static`.