# django admin static files stopped working after upgrade to 1.4

Tags: django, django-admin, django-staticfiles, django-media

Setting up static files in django has always been a nightmare to me. When it comes to dealing with django static content I get depressed and feel dumb and stupid. I never really cared about getting **admin** media files served as static ones since I barely use admin interface and there is no impact on performance.

It has worked quite ok with this dev setup until I upgraded to 1.4

> settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'd:/~Sasha/Portman/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin-media/'
```

> urls.py

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 
    'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

I looked up django 1.4 "what's new" documentation from can't figure what it is I need to change to get things back on track...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX is deprecated in Django 1.4. The admin uses the [staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) app now which was introduced in Django 1.3. Also make sure you don't miss to setup the static file development view as described at the end of the [documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view).